# Using member of to filter in many to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have this **problem**, to begin I have this example class

```
@Entity
public class A  {
    private String name;
  @id
  private Integer id;
  
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "formof_undertaking_subproduct", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
    private Set<b> bSet;
```

and I want to do this query

```
@Query("select distinct entity from A entity where :bId member of entity.b.id")
List<A> getAbyB(@Param("Bid")Integer Bid);
```

but when I execute this query I get this eception:

Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type

Because for some reason, it expected a B object, but I want to use a B.id the integer id.

Any idea to solve it?
thanks for your time and sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: What did you intend "entity.b.id" to be - did you mean to use bSet instead of b? "select distinct entity from A entity, join entity.bSet b where b.id = :bId".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have done a new query using a simple join, the query would be:

```sql
select distinct entity from A entity join entity.b other where other.id = :id;
```